# How to get smooth lines in a WPF Toolkit Chart LineSeries?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpftoolkit, charts

I'm creating a chart using WPF toolkit.  The chart has some lineseries in it.  I want to modify the lineseries so that I have smooth lines instead of straight lines.  Is that even possible?  I've been googling the problem for a while and have not come up with the answer.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no built in series which will achieve what you want, maybe you can create your own which draws splines rather than regular lines.

A quick Google points to this [SplineSeries](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/11/adding-a-smoothed-line-series-bezier-curve-to-a-visiblox-chart/), which may be a good starting point for you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can look into a Moving Average to smoothen the line. 
eg:

```
chart1.DataManipulator.FinancialFormula(FinancialFormula.MovingAverage, "10", series1, series2);
```